# Creating a Hyperlink to a different TabItem in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a WPF application with multiple TabItems within a TabControl. In one of the TabItems, I want to have a Hyperlink that when clicked, changes the view from the current TabItem, to one of the other TabItems.

I've looked into the NavigateURI property of Hyperlink but I haven't found a way to set that to be a separate tab in the same window. Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: Do you have to use an actual Hyperlink or are you just looking for the visual representation of a Hyperlink, disregarding the underlying code?

Comment: No I do not need an actual Hyperlink. I guess I shouldn't have assumed that a Hyperlink would be necessary. I just need a way for a user to click on some text in one tab, and have the view be transferred to a different tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make a button, style it like a hyperlink, and change the tab control tabindex on the click of the button.

Comment: I feel like this could work, but it sounds like a hack. Is this really the best method?

Comment: WPF controls are designed to be restyled... I don't consider using a language feature as being a hack.

Comment: Filling in the details (this worked for me)...
In XAML: `<TabControl Name="TabController">`
In code-behind:  `TabController.SelectedIndex = 1;`  _Replace 1 with whatever the correct index is_